firebase hosting get google-site-verification
Where can I find google-site-verification on firebase hosting console?
I'm hoting website on firebase hosting and would like to change url of website.
When I did same process about year ago I was able to find it by following step.
Manage site->add custom domain->domain input->txt info

but when i try to do set up today I was only able to find a and txt record google-site-verification. On Advanced tab I can find 43 character long dns txt record, should I just paste that after google-site-verification= ?
Please don't tell me to look at official document. I've follow the official document as much as I can and was unable to setup correctly.
